# Multicolumn listview with expandable items when clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, mindscape

So i have a datagrid that was built with the mindscape datagrid control that looks like this:

[image]

I am not sure if i will be able to do this to the mindscape control, so this will be a question about any multi-column listview or datagrid.

When an item is clicked, and selected, I need to expand the item (hopefully with an animation/storyboard) downwards, to display a bunch of extra information about the item (rating graph, list of available locations, etc).

I honestly have no idea how to begin with this. I'm new to wpf. in winforms i would just create a custom listboxitem that controls it's own height, and listen to the selected event.

Comment: Don't use a `ListView`. Use a [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) and lookup its [`RowDetailsTemplate` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) in MSDN. Your required functionality is built in to the `DataGrid`.

Comment: @Sheridan: Thanks! that should be an answer though :p

Comment: This comment is a bit short for an answer, @caesay. I'll buff it out and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ListView` is not the best control to use for your requirements. Instead of the `ListView`, you should use a [`DataGrid` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Your required functionality is built in to the `DataGrid` as it has a row details section... from the [`DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

> You can customize the data presentation in the DataGrid by adding a row details section. Adding a row details section enables you to group some data in a template that is optionally visible or collapsed.
>
> You define the row details template as either inline XAML or as a resource. A data template that is added as a resource can be used throughout the project without re-creating the template. A data template that is added as inline XAML is only accessible from the control where it is defined.